# scanf not reading second arguement

Tags: c

I have the following code which I am trying to run.

I want the `scanf` function to take in three different inputs, with the first two being integers between `0` and `30`, and the third a string beginning with `@`.

The program compiles fine, but when I attempt to input the coordinates and the associated `@`symbol, I get a `0` in the `y` coordinate's place.

Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to fix it? 
Below is the code

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){ 
    int grid[30][30];
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<30;i++){    
        for(j=0; j<30;j++){
            grid[i][j]='.';
        }
    }    

    int x_coord;
    int y_coord;
    char type[2]; 

    scanf("%d %d %s",&x_coord,&y_coord,type);

    /*added extra whitespace*/
    printf("%i  %i %s",x_coord,y_coord,type);
    printf("\n");

    grid[x_coord][y_coord]=type[1];
    //end outer loop 

    for(i=0; i<30;i++){

        for(j=0; j<30;j++){
            printf("%c",grid[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return(0);
}//end main
```

Comment: As large as necessary the `char type[2];`

Comment: What's your input?  And is it all on one line?  I also suggest you provide an [mcve] -- it can be very helpful, especially with these hard to trace errors.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values)  to assure the operation was successful.    In the posted code the returned value should be 3,  Any other value indicates an error.   When using the '%s' format specifier, ALWAYS include a max-length modifier (that is one less that the length of the input buffer)

Comment: these nested loops: `for(i=0; i<30;i++){    
        for(j=0; j<30;j++){
            grid[i][j]='.';
        }
    }`  can be completely eliminated by changing this line: `int grid[30][30];` to: `int grid[30][30] = {{'.'}};`

Comment: regarding this line: `grid[x_coord][y_coord]=type[1];`   what will be set into the `grid[][]` will be a NUL byte ('\0')  Probably not what you want.  Also, what happens when the user enters values for `x_coord` and/or `y_coord` that are >= 30?   What if the user enters a negative number?   I.E. never trust the user to do the right thing, always check anything a user enters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you declared `char type[2];` and you are first entering `@` and then new character suppose `X` so in type it will go like this

`type[0] = @`

`type [1]='\0'`

so you should declare `char type[3];` this way 
so that

`type[0] = @`

`type [1]='X'`

`type [2]='\0'`

it will stored this way and you can get X by accessing `type [1]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are entrering @X for the string, where X is some single character, scanf is going to attempt to fill type with '@' 'X' and '\0'  (null byte added by scanf to mark the end of the string)

That's 3 bytes being stored in array that is only big enough for two.